# Why does 2d index update a list but not 1d?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand indexing in a list. I try:

```
x= [1,2,3,[4]]
x[0]=[34]
x[3][0]=95
```

which gives

```
[1, 2, 3, [95]]
```

but why is it not:

```
[34 2, 3, [95]]
```

?
Edit: apologies my code was:

```
x= [1,2,3,[4]]
y=list(x)
x[0]=[34]
x[3][0]=95
print (y)
```

Which gives the results I stated.

[image]

Comment: It should give you `[[34], 2, 3, [95]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I believe python list mutability doing strange things.

When you call

```
y = list(x)
```

It copies each element in the list x over to the list y.

This means it avoids mutability in the first dimension, but because the third element is copied normally under the hood, and it is a list, it remains mutable.

You can find out a bit more in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)

Also, as others have pointed out, you are setting

```
x[0] = [34]
```

Which sets the first element of x to a list, not a number so x would actually be

```
[ [34], 2, 3, [95] ]
```

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get why the two subscript changes y but the single subscript doesn't. I understand 34 should be [34].

Comment: @schoon because y is a list containing a copy of each element in x, this means they have the same value but are not the same variable. The value of a list however, is special. I believe this is because of pointers in C. What it means is that the value of a list variable is actually a number corresponding to the memory address of the actual list data. So when you copy a list, it just copies the number pointing to a memory location, not the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Your example gives does not gives 1 at index 0.
You replace at index 0 the int 1 with a list containing one element of int 34 at index 0.

That will give you:

```
[[34], 2, 3, [95]]
```